# Nodejs isn't accessible outside of raspberry pi with pihole running

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi4

### Context

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with pihole running on it. Pihole is working great.

### Issue

I'm trying to run a nodejs app on the R-PI and it shows I can access it at localhost:3000. When I load it on the Pi, it shows the information correctly. If I try and load it from my laptop, which is on the same network as the Pi, it won't respond.

### Additional Diagnostics

`sudo netstat -lptu`  confirms the following:

`tcp        0      0 localhost:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15369/node`

I'm able to access the Pihole admin interface from my laptop.

Comment: Are you listening to `localhost:3000` or just port `3000`? There is a difference between `net.listen(3000)` and `net.listen(3000, 'localhost')`

Comment: I have app.listen(3000, localhost) in the node code. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Now all you have to do is remove `localhost`. What `app.listen(3000, localhost)` means is listen to port 3000 but only on the network card that the specified domain name/ip address is bound to. In your case `localhost` is bound to a virtual network card called the loopback device. So it will **not** listen to packets coming in from any other network card - eg. the network card connected to the internet. So change it to `app.listen(3000)`

Comment: Note you only need the second argument if you have a machine with multiple network cards and **only if you don't want the server to serve all network cards**

Comment: Note that this is not a javascript/node.js/Express specific issue. This is just how TCP/IP works. The same is true in C/C++, Java, Swift, Go, Ruby, Python etc.